# window.moveTo not working in Google Developer Tool

Tags: javascript

Originally, I was trying to use `JavascriptExecutor` in `Java` to maximize a browser window. It wasn't working so I decided to try something simpler, do it using `Javascript` directly.

I'm experiencing something weird and would like some insight.

1. Open up Google Developer Tool on this page for example.
2. Move this page away from the top left corner of your computer screen, and un-maximize the window.
3. Try the following code:

   `window.moveTo(0, 0);`

   `window.resizeTo(screen.width, screen.height);`
4. Does your window move to the top left corner and maximize? Because mine doesn't.

Comment: No one else is experiencing this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

according to this chrome ticket, it is broken: [issue 2709](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=2709&can=1&q=moveto%20resize&colspec=ID%20Pri%20Mstone%20ReleaseBlock%20Area%20Feature%20Status%20Owner%20Summary).  I dont think it will be fixed anytime soon since the ticket has been around since Sept. 2008 and no one is assigned.  Also, looks like FF8 axed the feature too: [Bug 565541](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=565541)

Comment: Wow that's an old issue that has not been fixed...disappointing.

Comment: moving and resizing browser windows is almost a taboo - a lot of browser vendors have completely disabled support for it.

Comment: Yeah, because it can be maliciously exploited so easily. Just like opening many alert boxes.

Comment: It is 2022 now, and yet not working.