# Any way to move window in javascript now?

Tags: javascript, window-position

After searching the net and SO, it seems that most of the browsers have disabled the `resizeTo` and `moveTo` javascript functions, and hence nothing comes into affect. [This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8582163/1135954) and the comments point to some related bug-reports.

I intended to put 2 icons (align left and alight right) on a webpage that would move the window, so that it's easy for user to place the complete browser window accordingly. It would be useful to place it that way for the app.

So, now as it is being disabled, is there any way we can achieve this? Please let me know.

Comment: Putting things in particular locations within a page has nothing to do with the ability to move or resize the overall browser window.

Comment: oh.. sorry updated text. I do need to move the browser window.

Comment: You cannot move the browser window.